# Redirect subdomain with www. Code without www is working (Wildcard)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, server

Now i have rule in .htaccess redirect (**wildcard is on**) many subdomains to other domain.

For example:
subdomain123.domain.com --> other-domain.co.uk/subdomain123

but redirect with **www** don't work. For example: 
**www.**subdomain123.domain.com --> other-domain.co.uk/subdomain123 - **404 error** - please help with www.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} .
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://other-domain.co.uk/%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the condition to optionally match a "www":

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} .
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://other-domain.co.uk/%2 [R=301,L,QSA]
```